# Latex Workshop - recipe tool to copy PDF file

Tags: latex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to achieve a copy tool to move the PDF file to a different folder than the compiled one.

The idea behind this is to have the main tex files in a cloud base folder (onedrive), but prevent to generate all the files in OneDrive (because it sync the generated files...).

So I tried to make a new tool. But unfortunatly, it isn't working. Can someone help me with this ?

I'm on Windows 10.

I tried with copy (but it isn't a known command). So I tried with xcopy. It seems to find the command, but it tells that the number of parameters are wrong....

```
{
   "name": "copyPDF",
   "command": "xcopy",
   "args": [
     "%TMPDIR%/%DOCFILE%.pdf",
     "%DIR%/PDF/%DOCFILE%.pdf",
     "/y",
   ]
}
```

Comment: You could have a look at ltx2any, this is a tex automation tool which will automatically have all the auxiliary  files in a tmp folder

Answer (score 6):

I've just tried to do the exact same thing.
It took me longer than I'd like to admit and it might be too late for your request, but it can help possible future visitors.

This is my settings.json:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
    {
      "name": "latexmk ➞ copyPDF",
      "tools": ["latexmk", "copyPDF"]
    }
  ],

"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "command": "latexmk",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "-pdf",
            "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "copyPDF",
        "command": "cmd.exe",
        "args": [
            "/c", 
            "copy",  
            "%OUTDIR%\\%DOCFILE%.pdf", 
            "%DIR%",
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
],
```

Comment: Well, you are right, sooner or later someone might need this and this is me. So the important take-away here is that latex-workshop does not really run inside `cmd` which I thought it did. One thing though: you could have just used `%DOC_EXT%` instead of `%OUTDIR%\\%DOCFILE%.pdf`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. it works for me too. In my case %DIR% is not working, any clue why? (P.S. I am using texlive)

Answer (score 1):

Had some problems with rheinert.leon's answer, mainly because of spaces in the filenames. Here's a a powershell tool version that accounts for that:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "copyPDF",
            "command": "powershell.exe",
            "args": [
                "copy '%OUTDIR%\\%DOCFILE%.pdf' %DIR%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        }
...
],
```